# Running sbt in cygwin throws Access is denied exception?

Tags: cygwin, sbt

I use sbt with cygwin.

sbt produces some artifacts and in between it throws `Access is denied` exception.

```
[debug]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\data\code\Project\NAUNSW011MyUserName.sbt (Access is    denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.Using$$anonfun$fileReader$1.apply(Using.scala:86)
    at sbt.Using$$anonfun$fileReader$1.apply(Using.scala:86)
    at sbt.Using$$anon$2.openImpl(Using.scala:72)
    at sbt.OpenFile$class.open(Using.scala:46)
    at sbt.Using$$anon$2.open(Using.scala:70)
```

The artifact directory is owned by `MyUsername` and the artifacts are produced with `drwx------+` permissions.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Please check your username password / domain name. Because  *permission denied errors* will come when you entered wrong username or password.

Comment: Hi Arun,Where to check and what to verify.

Comment: Can you post your build files? What's your sbt version (execute `sbt about`)? What are the results when you execute sbt from a regular Windows shell, outside cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue while building on windows platform.
In my case I had machine behind proxy. I followed steps mentioned in http://www.typesafe.com/activator/docs under section (behind proxy) still could not proceed
then I deleted **.sbt** directory under my C:\Users\MyUserName\ location.
again went to my project directory and run activator run. This solved my issue.
Hope this would help to someone who got similar issue.